# Comparing multiple adjacent cells - Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, string-comparison, worksheet, time-and-attendance

I hope this is not a duplicate. I have an attendance tracker in Excel.

The columns are days of the year (1/1/2018 - 12/31/2018 from B to NB) and the rows are employees names.

Days off are identified as V = Vacation, S = Sick and O= Scheduled day off. I am tasked with finding specific instances where employees call in sick before or after a day off. I would like to do this in worksheet as opposed to VBA, so that the end user can make adjustments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional formatting. Select the range from B2 - NB(lastrow of employees). Choose conditional formatting, New Rule, Use formula. Then enter this formula:

```
=AND(B2="S",OR(A2="O",C2="O"))
```

and choose the formatting to fill them in yellow. Click OK

Comment: Great idea. Thanks!